# OkHttp WebSocket RejectedExecutionException when try to restart

Tags: java, websocket, okhttp

I have this client:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .pingInterval(Duration.ofMinutes(3))
            .readTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(0))
            .build();
```

And this methods for start and stop:

```
private WebSocket webSocket = null;
private MyListener wsListener = null;

private void start(){

    if(webSocket != null){ return; }

    wsListener = new MyListener();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws")
        .build();

    webSocketBinance = okHttpClient.newWebSocket(request, wsListener); //here triggers error

}

private void stop(){

    if(webSocket == null){ return; }

    webSocket.close(1000, "{\"reason\": \"With love\"}");
    webSocket= null;

    okHttpClient.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
    okHttpClient.connectionPool().evictAll();

    wsListener = null;

}
```

Sometimes I want to restart the connection like this:

```
start();

Thread.sleep(10_000);

//restart connection
stop();
start(); //here triggers the error
```

But at `start()` I get this error:

```
java.io.InterruptedIOException: executor rejected
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.executeOn(RealCall.kt:501)
    at okhttp3.Dispatcher.promoteAndExecute(Dispatcher.kt:184)
    at okhttp3.Dispatcher.enqueue$okhttp(Dispatcher.kt:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.enqueue(RealCall.kt:164)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.connect(RealWebSocket.kt:165)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newWebSocket(OkHttpClient.kt:281)
    at foo.Foo.start(...)

Caused by: 
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: 
    Task okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall@2aceadd4 rejected from 
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@24aed80c
    [Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
    
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2080)
    
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:832)
    
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1365)
    
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.executeOn(RealCall.kt:498)
    
... 8 more
```

Comment: I'm not very knowledgable about OKHttp in general, but to me it seems that the culprit might be `.readTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(0))`.  Try increasing that 0 to 10 000. Does it take ten seconds before it crashes now?

Comment: @LajosArpad, In doc says if I set it on 0, means no timeout.

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: @LajosArpad, yes I did, and is still same error.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately I cannot help you further.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. @KunLun Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @section117, In `stop` I am making OkHttpClient and WebSocket `null`. And in `start` create a new client and websocket

Comment: @KunLun Yes, I got it now. Thank you. The problem lies in this line, `okHttpClient.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();` . When it is shutdown, it will shutdown the TaskExecutor rejecting any further connections. I closed the WebSocket without shutting down the OkHttpClient and then tried to reconnect which works fine. In OkHttpClient documentation it is mentioned that shutting down is not necessary. [OkHttp API](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/#shutdown-isnt-necessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in my case was to create a new `OkHttpClient` and `WebSocket` every time when I want to restart.